# Check if current term is a child of another term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, archives, terms

I'm attempting to make an archive template that will apply only to subcategories of a particular term. My structure looks something like this:

- Events (main taxonomy)

  - Tradeshow

    - Show subcat 1
    - Show subcat 2
  - Other taxonomies

I want `Show subcat 1` and `Show subcat 2` (and any other subcategories) to all get the same archive template. This is one of my attempts at it, which is definitely not working. Here's the code from my `functions.php`.

```
    add_filter( 'template_include', 'kd_event_subcategory_archive' );

    function kd_event_subcategory_archive( $template ) {
        $term = get_queried_object()->term_id;
        if ( $term->parent == 'tradeshow' ) {
            $event_subcat = locate_template( 'taxonomy-tradeshow-subcategory.php' );

            return $event_subcat;
        }

        return $template;
    }
```

I can't seem to figure out how to properly check if a term is the child of my `tradeshow` term.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two problems that have thwarted your check:

```
    $term = get_queried_object()->term_id;
    if ( $term->parent == 'tradeshow' ) {
```

Starting with:

```
    $term = get_queried_object()->term_id;
```

Here `$term` contains the ID of a term, not a term object. Lets assume this is term number 5, the result is:

```
    $term = 5;
    if ( $term->parent == 'tradeshow' ) {
```

Which won't work. `$term` is a number, not an object, so you cant do `->parent` on it.

The fix is to just use the queried object directly:

```
    $term = get_queried_object();
```

Which leads us to the next problem:

```
    if ( $term->parent == 'tradeshow' ) {
```

The parent isn't a string, it's a term ID. `0` if there is no parent, else it's the ID of the parent term, as shown if we look up `WP_Term`:

```
/**
 * ID of a term's parent term.
 *
 * @since 4.4.0
 * @var int
 */
public $parent = 0;
```

So you need to acquire the tradeshow term in advance to find out its ID. Usually, for these scenarios, developers will not hardcode the slug, but instead provide a setting that lists terms, and store the ID as an option to avoid this kind of lookup, and increase flexibility

But in this case you can use the `get_term_by` function, e.g.

```
$tradeshow = get_term_by('slug', 'tradeshow', 'events')
```

Then using:

```
$tradeshow->term_id === $term->parent
```

### Problems and Advice

These are additional items I wanted to mention that are unrelated

#### Debugging

Using `var_dump`, a debugger, or some other tool to see what the contents of `$term` was would have revealed these problems.

Additionally, PHP error logs will be full of warnings and notices pointing at the if statement for trying to do the equivalent of `5->parent` which makes no sense to PHP. Pay attention to error logs. I'd recommend using the query monitor plugin as an easy way to catch unexpected warnings

#### The Queried object isn't always a term

This code will run on every page load:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'kd_event_subcategory_archive' );

function kd_event_subcategory_archive( $template ) {
    $term = get_queried_object()->term_id;
    if ( $term->parent == 'tradeshow' ) {
```

But what if the user visits a date archive or an author archive? Now the code runs anyway, generating errors. So this filter needs tests to check if the user is on a taxonomy archive, and that the taxonomy matches.

It may even be a singular post, and if the trade show term has a term ID of 5, and you're on the post or page with ID 5, then you'll get a post showing on a taxonomy archive.

I suspect though that it would be easier to use a separate taxonomy.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object

> - if you're on a single post, it will return the post object
> - if you're on a page, it will return the page object
> - if you're on an archive page, it will return the post type object
> - if you're on a category archive, it will return the category object
> - if you're on an author archive, it will return the author object
> - etc.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough and helpful answer! That worked perfectly. I also wrapped the code in `if ( is_tax() ) { //code }`, which if I understand correctly should check for custom taxonomy archive page.

Answer (score 6):

All these answers are so overpowered and extremely long. I've just used this in 2 lines of code:

```
$term = get_queried_object();
$is_parent = $term->parent == 0 ? true : false;
```

Essentially, this is just checking if the parent is 0, if it is, then it's the parent. Else, it will be a child.

Super simple.